# Prove that $|Z(G)|=p$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be a non-abelian group of order $p^3$, $p$ prime. Show that $Z(G)$ is a group of order $p$. Deduce that $G/Z(G)$ is abelian.

From the class equation I can get that $p| |Z(G)|$, so $|Z(G)|=\{p,p^2,p^3\}$
it can't be of the order $p^3 $ because that would give us that $G$ is abelian.

If $|Z(G)|=p^2$ how to continue ? I don't see how a contradiction can appear.

Any hints how to continue ?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3548123/g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-abelian) answers the question. Or: pick $x\notin Z(G)$ and conclude that $G=\langle x,Z(G)\rangle$, hence $G$ abelian, hence $Z(G)=G$.

Comment: There's a standard result which says that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian. See if you can prove this (or find it in a textbook).

Answer (score 3):

Let us use that $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic iff $G$ is abelian. Using this, let us prove the result:

We know that $| Z(G)|\in\{p,p^2,p^3\}$ ($Z(G)\neq 0$ since $p$-groups have non trivial center). By hypothesis $G$ is not abelian, so $|Z(G)|\neq p^3$. If $|Z(G)|= p^2$ then $|G/Z(G)|=p $, and so $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic (a group of prime order is always cyclic), which is a contradiction since $G$ is not abelian. Then $|Z(G)|=p$

For the second part notice that $|G/Z(G)|=p^2 $. Since there are only two groups of order $p^2$, which are $C_{p^2}$ and $C_p\times C_p$, both of them abelian, then $G/Z(G)$ must be abelian.

Answer (score 2):

While one can prove this using the oft-quoted result that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian, this fact is not necessary to prove the result.

Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that the order of $Z(G)$ is exactly $p^2$. Since $G\neq Z(G)$, let $x\in G$ be an element with $x\notin Z(G)$.

Then $\langle Z(G),x\rangle$ is strictly larger than $Z(G)$, and hence must have order $p^3$ (since it divides $p^3$ but is strictly larger than $p^2$). Therefore, $\langle Z(G),x\rangle = G$.

But now let $a,b\in Z(G)\cup\{x\}$ be two generators. If at least one of them lies in $Z(G)$, then $ab=ba$. And if this is not the case, then they are both equal to $x$, so again $ab=xx=ba$. Thus, any two elements in the generating set commute, and that implies that $G$ is abelian.

But that yields that $Z(G)=G$ is of order $p^3$, a contradiction. Thus, the order cannot be exacty $p^2$.

Comment: Right, but that is very similar to the proof of the result you want to avoid, so I dont see why you don't want to use it.

Comment: @Marcos: You claimed that it was **necessary** to use the result. That one **needs to know** the result. It's not, and you do not. This argument does not even require you to know what a quotient group is. Drop the assertion that one *must* use the result in question, and I have no problems with what you write. For instance, if your answer began with "You can prove this using the fact that..." instead of "You need to know that..."