# If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, why is $G$ only abelian and not also cyclic?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, quotient-group

If the factor group with respect to the center of $G$ is cyclic, then $(aZ(G))^n=gZ(G)$ for some $n$ and any $g$, where both $a$ and $g$ are from $G$ (and $a^n$ is, too).

Because of the definition of the operation on the factor group it should be correct that $a^nZ(G)=gZ(G)$.

How come $G$ is not cyclic, too?

Comment: Pick an abelian group $G$ which is not cyclic.  What is $G/Z(G)$?

Comment: I'll go a step further - start with the simplest case, $C_2\times C_2$, and see what goes wrong.

Comment: Why would $a^nZ(G) = gZ(G)$ imply that $G$ is cyclic? It just means that $a^n$ and $g$ are in the same coset of $Z(G)$.

Comment: @hardmath Ok I'll try: If abelian, G=Z(G). Left coset of some element g is all the combinations gz where z in Z(G) (here z in G). So the set of all cosets is basically all the combinations of elements from G, which is G, but that can't be it.

Comment: My point was that if $G$ is abelian, $G/Z(G)$ is the trivial group (and hence cyclic).  But $G$ *can* be abelian without being cyclic, as @StevenStadnicki's minimal example shows.

Comment: I understand the example. How do you obtain the trivial group?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I see, there's no generator.

Comment: We have $G/Z$ cyclic $\implies$ $G/Z=${$e$} because of $G=Z$. So, $G/Z$ is never a non-trivial cyclic group. In particular, the index of $Z$ cannot be a cyclic number greater than $1$, especially it cannot be a prime.

Comment: @Peter Is there a simple way to get $G/Z=\{e\}$?

Comment: Note that $G$ must be abelian, so $G=Z$.

Comment: @Peter I get that, but when I try to compute G/Z via the definitions of cosets G/H I get the entire G instead of {e}.

Comment: @TanzWalzer No, you get the one-element group $G/G = \{G\}$.

Comment: @Bungo Now I understand, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been ressurrected, so we might as well.

The fact that if $G/N$ is cyclic and $N\subseteq Z(G)$ then $G$ is abelian (and hence $G/Z(G)$ is in fact trivial) [has been asked and answered before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63087/if-g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-abelian) ([many times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12320/proof-that-if-group-g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-commutative)) and I have [expressed my dislike for that phrasing several times, too](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3269102/a-strange-result-if-g-mathrmzg-p/3272052#3272052).

Now the question here is: why is it we can't conclude that $G$ itself was in fact cyclic? The argument given is okay as far as it goes: there exists $g\in G$ such that for every $a\in G$ there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $aN = g^nN$ (I'm using my formulation of a central subgroup $N$). That means that $a^{-1}g^n\in N$, not that $a=g^n$, so we cannot conclude that $G=\langle g\rangle$.

Of course, this is a much more general phenomenon. It is just a reflection that, in general, if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $x,y\in G$ are such that $xH=yH$, we cannot conclude $x=y$ (except in the literally trivial case of $H=\{e\}$). We can only conclude that there exists $h\in H$ with $x=yh$.